# CSS Immediate Child Selector Not Selecting

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<style>
table > tr > th {
 color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>a</th>
  <th>b</th>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I just can't see why the text in the cells are not red. Could you show me what i am missing.

Comment: By the way, "table > tbody > tr > th {
 color: red;
}" is making the text red.

Comment: so you have your answer :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif, i want to know why the css code in the question is not working. Am i not doing everything according to the rules?

Comment: you answered your self by your own comment ;)

Comment: you have a working code and non working code ... so what is the difference between them ? the difference is the answer

Comment: let me explain my concern then. I should not be worrying about how the browser will manipulate and modify my html code while i am writing the css code. I check my code against https://validator.w3.org/ and it says your html is correct. So if it's correct, i am allowed to place tr inside table. My html is correct and my css is correct. In the linked answer, i see no rule stated against tr inside table. I just don't like surprises when it comes to coding. Can you understand my concern?

Comment: `I should not be worrying about how the browser will manipulate and modify my html code` --> no no, you should be worried :) because it's not you that decide but the specification ;) we all get suprised by some behavior but when we understand them, we work with them

Comment: @TemaniAfif, that's what i am saying. I should be worried about the specification and the browser should behave according to the specification. If the tbody was a must, I would already add it at the first place so there would be no problem.

Comment: @KodFun: By that logic, does that mean `body > p` should not match `<html><p></html>`, which, aside from the DOCTYPE and title, [is also valid HTML](https://checker.html5.org/?showsource=yes&doc=data%3Atext%2Fhtml%3Bcharset%3Dutf-8%2C%3C%21DOCTYPE+html%3E%250A%3Chtml%3E%250A%3Ctitle%3Ebody+%3E+p%3C%2Ftitle%3E%250A%3Cp%3E%3C%2Fhtml%3E)?

Comment: That's why I said "aside from the DOCTYPE and title"

Comment: @BoltClock, i checked with doctype and it was interestingly validated. And yes, `body > p' does matches it. From your example, i understand that what body is for html is like what tbody is for table. Thanks for the example.

Comment: @BoltClock, but still i don't like the way it works. It's not transparent. On html, it allows something, you write css according to that accepted html and it doesn't work. It just doesn't seem robost to me. This is just my opinion. Thanks for your valuable comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `table tr th` instead of `table > tr > th` because a `tbody` element is added  as a parent element to `tr` by the browser and since the [direct child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) `>` is used, it won't style the `th`

```css
table tr th {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>a</th>
    <th>b</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have are table headers. Firstly, if you want a table cell, use the `<td>` tag. You do not have to use `table > tr > td`. If you want to color specific cells, use a class to identify them:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<style>
.cells {
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td class="cells">a</td>
  <td class="cells">b</td>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

If not, just use the tag:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<style>
td {
 color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>a</td>
  <td>b</td>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: my question is about > selector.